# Nested loop runs super slow

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Rotate_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 36
        For j = 1 To 36
            Cells(j + 40, 43 - i).Value = Cells(i + 2, j + 6).Value
       Next j
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: We're going to need way more background to this problem to really get a feel for why it's running slowly

Comment: Turn off calculation? This seems like a pretty simple loop. If it's slow it may just be that your book is slow and needs some fixing.

Comment: Just have a 36x36 table with some numbers in it, some are empty.  Just copy it from the top of the sheet to somewhere further below with the numbers moved.

Comment: Maybe this helps - just picture a square with 36 x 36 cells, each cell has a number in it, e.g. 1 for cell A1, 2 for cell  B1,  37 for A2, all the way to 1296 for AJ36.

Comment: I think the point that the other commentators are trying to make is that if the only thing going on is a simple data copy, 1296 operations should not be "slow" in and of itself.

Comment: Consider getting your source range into a 2D variant array, then writing a function that manipulates/rotates that array, and then write the rotated array in a single operation. No individual cell needs to be accessed in the process.

Comment: @Comintern, it's not a straight copy. Thgere is some inversion in the `43 - i` column designator.

Comment: Straight copy in the sense that it reads a value from a cell and writes it to another cell. This runs in under a tenth of a second on my machine.

Comment: @Comintern, formula calculation and/or conditional formatting are a copy of things that could slow down the direct transfer of values.

Comment: on a side note: Isn't `integer` dying out? should use `long` instead

Answer (score 2):

Use a couple of arrays for processing so you aren't looping through the worksheet cells.

```
Sub Rotate_Click()
    Dim i As long, j As long, val1 as variant

    val1 = cells(3, 7).resize(36, 36).value2
    redim val2(lbound(val1, 1) to ubound(val1, 1), _
               lbound(val1, 2) to ubound(val1, 2))

    For i = 1 To 36
        For j = 1 To 36
            val2(j, 37 - i) = val1(i, j)
       Next j
    Next i

    cells(41, 7).resize(ubound(val2, 1), ubound(val2, 2)) = val2

End Sub
```